# does hadoop distribute a file by copyFromLocal

Tags: hadoop, distributed

I copied a 10Gig file from local file system to hdfs(by using -copyFromLocal), is it distributed between all datanodes or it's just on namenode? how can I be sure that it has been distributed on all datanodes?

Answer (score 1):

As we known the metadata of a file is stored on Namenode and actual data are stored on Datanodes of the cluster.

If you have moved the 10 Gig file then definitely metadata of this file would be stored on Namenode and data would be stored on Datanodes. But the size of your file is much larger than the block-size(normally 64 MB or 128 MB), then that file data would be definitely stored on many blocks of different Datanodes (because of replication factor) of the cluster.

Only the Namenode has the knowledge of those data location in the cluster.

Answer (score 1):

Whenever a file is copied to HDFS, it will be distributed among the slave nodes. Depending on the size of the file, it might get distributed on a few or many datanodes. you can check the distribution of your file using the 'fsck' commands. Use the below command to check the file distribution parameters.

```
$ hdfs fsck  <absolute path to your file on hdfs>
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the `copyFromLocal` operation will distribute the chuncks of your input data over the cluster along with the replicated copies. Any operation by which you write contents to HDFS will distribute the data over the cluster.

For any reasons the Namenode service will not store the data, where as it just prepares the list data nodes available to store the given input data across the cluster whenever any client ,including `hadoop -copyFromLocal`, tries to write the data. Once the client obtains the list of data nodes from namenode , then the client takes care of writing the chuncks of data to the data nodes along with the replication.

The **Anatomy of File Write** topic from Chapter 3 of Hadoop Definitive Guide will help you to understand the above scenario clearly.

Anyhow you can very well check how the chunks/blocks of your data were distributed over the cluster by using the following command,

```
   hadoop fsck <hdfs_file_path> -files -blocks -locations
```

This command will let you know the file size, number of blocks, replicated blocks, corrupt blocks, missing blocks. Moreover it will show the more details of every blocks including the locations wherever the blocks are stored and the health status of the blocks.